# Chrome doesn't adjust bottom of document to bottom of window when element gets hidden

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I'm hiding a div (at the bottom of the page) which causes the overall height of the document to shrink.

When I scroll down all the way to the bottom of the page before hiding the div, Chrome correctly adjusts the bottom of the document to the bottom of the window.

When I don't scroll down all the way but leave at least a pixel below the windows bottom edge before hiding the div, Chrome doesn't adjust the bottom of the document to the bottom of the window. Instead the document shrinks and below Chrome’s grey fabric background shows. Then as soon as I scroll the page at least a pixel, Chrome adjusts the document to the window again.

This can be reproduced on any website with Chrome’s Dev Tools. Scroll almost(!) down to the bottom, select any element and set `display:none` or `height:0`.

I use Chrome 29 on OS X 10.8.4. Is this a known bug?

A workaround is using jQuery’s scrollTop function to scroll up a pixel after hiding the element. Chrome then adjusts the document.

```
var y = $(window).scrollTop();
$(window).scrollTop(y-1);
```

Now, it get's tricky when I want to use jQuery’s slideToggle() to hide the element. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please post your HTML, JavaScript, and CSS code?  I just set the footer element to 'display: none' on this very question page, and I'm not seeing Chrome misbehave.

Comment: It doesn't take specific code on my side. I get this misbehavior also on this site’s footer element. Sure you didn't scroll down all the way? Are you on OS X as well?

Comment: I'm certain that I did not scroll all the way to the bottom, as I was trying to recreate the behavior you described.  I am not on OS X (I'm using Linux), so this is very likely an OS X-specific bug.  You may want to report this to the browser vendor.

Answer (score 0):

Since we seem to have verified it, yes, this is now a known bug ;)  Please be sure to mention that the behavior is inconsistent across operating systems in your report to the browser vendor.